# How to print all objects that are referenced by another class

Tags: java

I want to print all objects from the class "Contato" that references the object phonebook1 (not sure if I worded it correctly)

basically I want the method to print:

ListAllContacts(phonebook1);

1. Bob
2. Mary
3. Ana

and if I put phonebook2 as the argument:

ListAllContacts(phonebook2);

1. Jacob

```
public class Contato {
    public String nome;
    public String numero;
    public Agenda agenda;

    public Contato(String nome, String numero, Agenda agenda){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.agenda = agenda;   
    }
}

public class Agenda {
    public String nomeAgenda;

    public void ListAllContacts(Agenda agenda){
    }
}

public class AgendaTelefonica {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Agenda phonebook1 = new Agenda();
        Agenda phonebook2 = new Agenda();
        phonebook1.nomeAgenda = "phonebook1";
        phonebook2.nomeAgenda = "phonebook2";

        Contato c1 = new Contato("Bob", "123", phonebook1);
        Contato c2 = new Contato("Mary", "126", phonebook1);
        Contato c3 = new Contato("Ana", "568", phonebook1);
        Contato c4 = new Contato("Jacob", "998", phonebook2);       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is wrong and/or inefficient for this. It'd be better if you access objects by placing them in an ArrayList inside of the Agenda class. Here is an example:

```
public class Contato {
    public String nome;
    public String numero;
    public Agenda agenda;

    public Contato(String nome, String numero, Agenda agenda){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.agenda = agenda;
    }
}

public class Agenda {
    public String nomeAgenda;

    private ArrayList<Agenda> agendas;

    public Agenda() {
        agendas = new ArrayList<Agenda>();
    }

    public void ListAllContacts(){
        for (Agenda a : agendas) {
            System.out.println(a.nome);
        }
    }

    public void add(Agenda a) {
        agendas.add(a);
    }
}

public class AgendaTelefonica {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Agenda phonebook1 = new Agenda();
        Agenda phonebook2 = new Agenda();
        phonebook1.nomeAgenda = "phonebook1";
        phonebook2.nomeAgenda = "phonebook2";

        phonebook1.add(new Contato("Bob", "123", phonebook1));
        phonebook1.add(new Contato("Mary", "126", phonebook1));
        phonebook1.add(new Contato("Ana", "568", phonebook1));
        phonebook2.add(new Contato("Jacob", "998", phonebook2));       
    }   
}
```